# JS marquee/ticker using requestAnimationFrame not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to build my own JS infinite ticker/marquee. The idea is fairly simple...

1. Get the width of the first item in the `ul`
2. Animate the marquee `ul` the width of first item
3. Once it's finished, remove the first item and add to the end, then do the same over and over.

I am using requestAnimationFrame to work out when the animation ends and then to retrigger the process again but the times that it seems to 'fire' don't seem to match the widths of the items. Where am I going wrong?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooYvZw

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    })();

var $marquee = $('footer.marquee ul'),
    $marqueeContents = $marquee.children();

//scroller.append(marqueeContents.clone()).append(marqueeContents.clone());

(function marquee(){
    requestAnimationFrame(marquee);
    var li = $marqueeContents.eq(0),
        liWidth = li.outerWidth();
    console.log(liWidth);
    $marquee.animate({'left': -liWidth}, 5000, 'linear', function() {
        $marquee.css({'left': 0}).find("li:last").after($marquee.find("li:first"));
    });
})();
```

Comment: [Do Marquees Have Good UX?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/do-marquees-have-good-ux), [What are arguments against the usage of a ticker / marquee on websites?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76951/what-are-arguments-against-the-usage-of-a-ticker-marquee-on-websites)

Comment: @Andreas Appreciated but this isn't related... it's a very specific need.

Comment: `Once it's finished, remove the first item and add to the end` which part of your code does that?

Comment: @JaromandaX The callback in the .animate

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry, wasn't reading it right

Comment: So if I read it correctly, you are starting one new jQuery animation which lasts 5s every 60th of seconds... This means that when the first callback will fire, 300 animations will be running, and then all their callbacks will fire every 60th of a second.

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah sounds right but don’t know where I’m going wrong?

Comment: Well what's the purpose of your rAF loop?

Comment: @Kaiido Maybe I’m not understanding it correctly but I thought it would re-fire the animation once it’s complete?

Comment: No it will refire it in a 60th of a second, every 60th of a second.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah seems fairly pointless then. Are you able to help me work out a solution? Does my timeout need to be the width of the li * 1000 / speed? Or maybe I could use animationEnd?